# Modify PWA link in firefox for android

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, firefox-for-android

I 'installed' a page as a PWA with Firefox for Android; however, the entrypoint url specified in the page's manifest is not the url I want to open. In my example, Instagram, it opens instagram.com, but I want instagram.com?variant=following and not the useless recommended page. Therefore, my question is: Is there any easy way to modify this link on my home screen (or, alternatively, tell firefox about this before the link is created)? There are two solutions I can think of, both of which seem suboptimal:

1. Don't install as a PWA, but as a link to the website: This is supposed to work if you click install when the page (and thus the manifest) wasn't able to load (eg. airplane mode) (haven't tried this though) - the page would open as a tab in firefox instead of a separate activity though
2. Somehow man-in-the-middle myself with an https proxy and rewrite the manifest before installing the PWA - this might work but seems like a lot of work.

Ideally, I'd just modify the home screen entry and change the URL there.

Versions:
Android 14 / Pixel 7 (not rooted)
Firefox 119.1.1

Comment: by "install" you mean the function "Add to Home Screen"?

Comment: @Robert yes and no - for websites that have a PWA manifest, this button changes to `install`, and it then doesnt open as a tab but as its own thing

Comment: You cant change the workings of the PWA.  It is basically a whole application in javascript.

Comment: @RohitGupta i mean a PWA is literally just a website with an additional json file that defines an entrypoint url, so if i can change that url somehow i literally can

Comment: Sorry, my PWAs are not that.  They are full applications, resistant to tampering.